# how to convert a character array to decibel

Tags: c

I have some problems in my code:

```
UINT8 PoWerSignal = MyScanResults.signal;
char Signal[8];

sprintf(Signal, "%d", PoWerSignal);

float decibel = 0;
decibel = 10 * log(Signal);

dbgwrite("SIGNAL:     ");
_dbgwrite(decibel);
```

There is one error:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'logf'

I don't know how to fix this or what it means.

Comment: Why do you write the `UINT8` to a string and then try to get the logarithm? `log(PoWerSignal);` should work just fine.

Comment: log takes a fload argument and not a char* argument

Comment: because the type of member structure (signal) defined by UNIT8

Comment: I understand that, but why don't you just write `decibel = 10*log(PoWerSignal);`? `PoWerSignal` is already a number, why write it to a string?

Comment: yes you are right,but it doesn't effect on final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are passing a `char` array (aka "string",  here: `Signal`, the *alphanumerical* representation of the value stored in `PoWerSignal`) to `log()`, which most likely does **not** expect such input, but a number.

You might like to pass the *numerical* representation of the function `log()`like so:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* To have the prototypes foe the printf family of functions. */

...

UINT8 PoWerSignal = MyScanResults.signal;

char Signal[8] = "";
snprintf(Signal, sizeof(Signal), "%d", PoWerSignal);

float decibel = 10. * log(PoWerSignal);

...
```

---

The function `_dbgwrite()` seems to expect an `char` array on the other hand. To conform to this create the a "string" using `snprintf()` out of `decibel` to pass into it, like so:

```
...

char descibel_str[64] = "";
snprintf(decible_str, sizeof(decibel_str), "%f", (double) decibel);

dbgwrite("SIGNAL:     ");
_dbgwrite(decibel_str);
```

---

Note on the usage of `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`: The former version of this "conversion" function does take care of not overflowing the target buffer, that is where the *alphanumerical* representation of the arguments passed are stored. This can easely happend and would provoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have added your code but there are some errors:C:\Users\hossein\Desktop\test2\taskFlyport.c:45: warning: implicit declaration of function 'snprintf'
C:\Users\hossein\Desktop\test2\taskFlyport.c:45: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'snprintf'
C:\Users\hossein\Desktop\test2\taskFlyport.c:53: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'float'

Comment: @HOsseiNSA: If `snprintf()` is not available on your platform go for `sprintf()` but take care the buffer to print to is large enough.

Comment: Now it works but the problem is all received signals are the same like this: "SIGNAL:     51.059456SSID:       Sitecom981A5D"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're sending a bad data type (signal). Perhaps this should be a float or unsigned int instead of a character array? "char" denotes a string of text, and you can't operate on it as a number.

Comment: thanks.but what does this warning mean:""warning: passing argument 1 of '_dbgwrite' makes pointer from integer without a cast""?

Comment: @HOsseiNSA: You are passing in an integer and the function expects a (`char`?) array. An array decays to a pointer.